# Zend Framework: form with label that has a few styles

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I would like to create a form with a label that would contain two different styles, for example:

"**Email** (enter your email):"

How can I do that? Right now I am using the `label` attribute of the `addElement()` method:

```
$form->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'label'    => 'Email',
    'required' => true,
));
```

With this method I only get a label attribute to the form tag, and can't use different styling inside it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already use the `Label` decorator ?
If yes, just use this code :

```
$form->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'label'    => '<strong>Email</strong> (enter your email)',
    'required' => true,
));
/* Here some code to add the Label decorator */
$form->getElement('email')->getDecorator('Label')->setOption('escape', false);
```

And this is done. I just added the `<strong>` tag to the label, and asked the `Label` decorator not to escape this tag.
It's also working for any html content. This is how I could put images in some checkboxes labels :) (country flags to choose the language)